# In the browser, how can I detect if a user has given microphone permissions?

Tags: javascript, browser, permissions, microphone

Not much more than the title. On the browser, I'm requesting the mic for use. How can I, as the dev, get access to if they've chosen and which choice they made? Thanks.

Comment: it will accept an error callback from you and call it when an error happens. This includes permission errors. Check html5 getusermedia api documentation.

Comment: See [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia).

Comment: As far as I can tell, getUserMedia lets me know if the browser supports media. I already have that. What I want to know is what choice they made when prompted for permission by the browser. How do I get that?